# Why is there null before a String while Reading data from a text File in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, null

I was writing a program that requires me to read Data from a text file and then create an object using that data, which is then stored in two-dimensional array. First, I'll begin by giving you a sample of the Data that I am reading from the text File.

```
Christian
Huygens
460
ICSE
D
1
J
-3
-4
-5
```

Note that there are no spaces between the lines in the actual text document. Now, I have to read this data and store it in array `Student a[30][100]` For that I've used the method `intialize_array()`, which is given below.

```
void initialize_array()throws IOException
{  BufferedReader br_1=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D1.txt"));
int i=0; //Filling only the first row
for(int j=0;j<100;j++) //Looping through all students in section A
           {   

                    String a=br_1.readLine(); //First name
                    if(a!=null)
                    {
                    String b=br_1.readLine(); //Surname
                    int c=Integer.parseInt(br_1.readLine());//School Number
                    String d=br_1.readLine();//Current Board
                    String e=br_1.readLine();//Form
                    int f=Integer.parseInt(br_1.readLine());//Stream
                    String g=br_1.readLine();//House Name 
                    int h=Integer.parseInt(br_1.readLine());
                    int m=Integer.parseInt(br_1.readLine());
                    int n=Integer.parseInt(br_1.readLine());
                    Student st=new Student(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,m,n); //These are all the fields of the Student class 
                    this.a[i][j]=st;
                    String empty=br_1.readLine();

                    }
                }
}
```

In total there are 30 sections and a maximum of hundred students can be included in one section. This code works only for one section and therefore, the row is pre-decided. For that particular row/section, I am essentially filling the students who belong to that section. Once I've done this, I use the display method of the Student class to display all the students in the section. This method is given below:

```
void display123()throws IOException
    {   initialize_array();

        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
        {  if(a[i][j]!=null)
            {   
              a[i][j].display();

        }
    }
}
```

For reference, the method `display()` of the student class is given below:

```
void display()throws IOException
{ 
    System.out.println("Name: "+first_name+" "+surname);
    System.out.println("School Number :"+school_number);
    System.out.println("House :"+house);
    System.out.println("Current Board :"+current_board);
    System.out.println("Form :"+form);
    System.out.println("Stream :"+stream);
    System.out.println("Late Mark(s) :"+late_mark);
    System.out.println("Absent Mark(s) :"+absent_mark);
    System.out.println("Present Mark(s) :"+present_mark);
}
```

The output of the previous method `display123()` is what alarms me. All the strings are displayed with a null in front of them, like this

```
Name: nullChristian nullHuygens
School Number :460
House :nullJ
Current Board :nullICSE
Form :nullD
Stream :1
Late Mark(s) :-3
Absent Mark(s) :-4
Present Mark(s) :-5
```

The Constructor for class Student is given below:

```
public Student(String f,String s,int ss,String c, String ff,int sss,String h,int l,int a,int p)
 {  first_name=first_name+f;
   surname=surname+s;
   school_number=ss;
   current_board=current_board+c;
   form=form+ff;
   stream=sss;
   house=house+h;
   late_mark=l;
   absent_mark=a;
   present_mark=p;
    }
```

Comment: Try trimming your strings.

Comment: Can you show the constructor for Student?

Comment: When would `if(a!=null)` ever be false? But seriously, looks like a data storage problem in the Student class that would be aided by trimming the strings

Comment: I've finally resolved to trimming strings, but I wanted to know why this is happening. @Peter, I've added the constructor for your reference. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Trimming the strings is just fixing the symptoms, not the root cause.

The reason for the "null" showing up is in the constructor:

```
first_name=first_name+f;
```

By default the `first_name` field will be initialized to the null value. The sum operator will convert it to the "null" string and add the given value of `f`.

So to fix this properly, remove the summations:

```
first_name=f;
```